# How to render JArray without square parentheses into JSON?

Tags: arrays, scala, json4s

When I render JArray object:

```
val json = compact(render(data))
```

I get JSON like that:

```
[
{object},
{object}
]
```

But I need to get next text data:

```
{object},
{object}
```

In other words, I need to get string without "open and end" square parentheses.

Is there any way to do that without go thought all elements and render each of them separately?

Comment: One possible solution is to re-write the `render` method to do the wrong thing and render JSON in an invalid format. While it is a possible solution, I would strongly advise against it (but I already spent a few minutes working on this so I felt like sharing this abomination). ;-) https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/Ax1aeMb5SSKekShQbbpJkA/24

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have found such a solution:

```
val json = compact(render(data))
val parentheses = "^\\[|\\]$".r
parentheses.replaceAllIn(json, "")
```